# Import of CSV Data ignoring the separator

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, csv-import

I'm using RStudio and  I wanted to import csv data. 
This data has 3 columns and they are separated by ",".

Now I type `test <- read.csv("data1.csv", sep=",")`
Data is imported but its imported as just ONE column.

Headers are okay, but also the headers (actually 3) are combined together in just one column.

If I set header=F, there was V1 as heading. So there really is just one column.
Why is my separator not working?

Comment: Sounds like the separator isn't really a comma. Can you actually show part of the input file? We really need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to help further.

Comment: in cvs data the first row is named as following:

Alter.des.Hauses,"Quadratfuß","Marktwert"

the second row is

33,1.812,"$90.000,00"

and so on. the names in the first row are my column names and every column then has numeric values

Comment: That sounds German. Have you tried `read.csv2`?

Comment: read.csv has a  sep="," and header=TRUE by default. I made an example with the two lines that you provided and test <- read.csv("data1.csv") works fine... Could you edit the question by adding a link to the real data?

Answer (score 0):

### try `read_csv()` from `readr` package

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/readr")
```

### with your sample input

```
library(readr)
file <- 'Alter.des.Hauses,"Quadratfuß","Marktwert"\n33,1.812,"$90.000,00"\n'
read_csv(file) # for the actual use read_csv("file.csv") ...
read_csv2(file)
```